# A proof of the fact that the rank of an abelian group is well defined.

Tags: group-theory

> $\bf 4.2.1.$ If $G$ is an abelian group, two maximal independent subsets consisting of elements with order a power of the prime $p$ have the same cardinality. The same is true of maximal independent subsets consisting of elements of infinite order. Thus $r_0(G)$, $r_p(G)$ and $r(G)$ depend only on $G$.
>
> ***Proof.*** Let $S$ be a maximal independent subset of elements of $p$-power order. If we replace each element of $S$ with order larger than $p$ by a suitable multiple, we obtain an independent subset $S_0$ consisting of elements of order $p$ such that $|S|=|S_0|$. If $g\in G[p]$, then $S\cup\{g\}$ is dependent and there is a relation $mg+\sum_im_is_i=0$ where $s_i\in S,m_i,n$ are integers and $mg\neq0$. Since $pg=0$, we have $\sum_ipm_is_i=0$ and $pm_is_i=0$. Hence $m_is_i\in\langle S_0\rangle$ and $g\in\langle S_0\rangle$.

Hi: Why does $g$ belong to $\langle S_0\rangle$? All I see is that $mg \in \langle S_0\rangle$.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. That said, you might want to explain the notation (or give a reference) as it is not clear what this all refers to.

Comment: $m$ is not a multiple of $p$, and $g$ has order $p$, so there exists an integer $n$ such that $nmg = g$. Thus, if $mg\in\langle S_0\rangle$, then $g\in \langle S_0\rangle$.

Comment: @mrtaurho: without the image my question is unintelligible. And I cant't write such a long text. I would be years writing.

Comment: @stf91: It took me about two minutes to write out the content of the image. I type fast, but it wouldn’t take longer than 5 minutes typing much slower than that. Please do try to avoid images; neither of the images you have used so far took long to type up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g\in G[p]$, $g$ has order $p$. Since $mg\neq 0$, then $m$ is not a multiple of $p$, and hence is relatively prime to $p$. Thus, there exist integers $n$ and $x$ such that $nm+xp=1$, so
$$g = 1g = (nm+xp)g = n(mg) + x(pg) = n(mg).$$
Hence, if $mg\in\langle S_0\rangle$, then $g\in\langle S_0\rangle$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. [